# ibm-cos-sdk putObject does not create the correct Binary Object

Tags: node.js, websphere, object-storage

Following the instructions from the [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-node#node-examples-new-file), I try to upload a file on a bucket.

If I upload a text file (i.e. a csv file), everything works as expected.

If I upload a binary string file (i.e. a pdf file) (read using [readAsBinaryString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString)), the file on cloud storage is wrong, only blank pages. The file size and the 256hash of the file changes.

[image]

I used all:

1. A buffer `Buffer.from(binaryString)`
2. A Uint8Array `new TextEncoder().encode(binaryString)`
3. A the binary string

on

```
putObject({
    Bucket: 'test-b',
    Key: key,
    Body: binaryString
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the binary stream of the file for PDF try to upload using the multipart file upload option to upload it.